# In R, using variable names, rather than column values, to turn columns binary

Tags: r, binary

I have a set of categorical columns in my dataset that I'll be turning into binary variables (1/0).

There are many of these, and currently, I've called the column names and values, transferred into a word document and then used the column values directly in the code:

```
binarydata<- rawdata3
my_cols = c(8:38, 48:52, 59:69, 96:118, 120:132, 145:148, 154:170, 223:330) 
binarydata[my_cols] <- as.integer(!is.na(binarydata[my_cols]))
```

Is there a way to do it using the variable names, instead of the values?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: It's hard to give a useful answer without a [representative sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) of data. I imagine there are already posts on SO that should answer your question, but it's hard to point you to them without actually knowing what's in your data

Comment: Not exactly sure if I understand your question. You already have `my_cols` as numbers now you want their equivalent column names and use it in the code? Why?

Comment: in case the column numbers change. I don't want to go through the process of finding the column numbers again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colnames` to subset.  `colnames` is more general compared to `names` as it can also work with `matrix`

```
nm1 <- colnames(binarydata)[my_cols]
binarydata[nm1] <- lapply(binarydata[nm1], function(x) +(!is.na(x)))
```

---

Also, using the `dplyr`, we can specify the column names in range (`:`)

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
      mutate(across(c(mpg:disp, wt:qsec), ~ +(!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: what does this do - does it change to 1 where a value is present, and 0 where value is not?

Comment: @Pre Yes, the `!` converts TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa.  The `+` coerces TRUE ->1 and FALSE -> 0

Answer (score 0):

This can also work, but it was not tested as no data was shared:

```
#Code
binarydata<- rawdata3
my_cols = c(8:38, 48:52, 59:69, 96:118, 120:132, 145:148, 154:170, 223:330) 
mynames <- names(binarydata)[my_cols]
binarydata[,mynames] <- as.integer(!is.na(binarydata[,mynames]))
```